# Apache alias issue with zend when accessed with other than index controller

Tags: apache, .htaccess, zend-framework

I have created an Apache alias
    http://www.domain.com/xyz
 pointing to public folder present in my Zend application.
    c:/wamp/www/xyz/public/

It is working fine when accessed with index controller, but when accessed with new controller it is showing server misconfiguration.

Working :
       http://www.domain.com/xyz/ (here this alias is pointing to public folder)

Server misconfiguration : 
      http://www.domain.com/xyz/controller2

this is the error with controller2: file c:/wamp/www/xyz/public/controller2.php doesn't exist..

This is my htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L]
```

I tried even with     RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [NC,L,QSA] and some other rewrite rules.

Can somebody help me..

Comment: mapping "controller2" to "controller2.php" suspiciously looks like the apache "MultiViews" directive is enabled in the apache config file. What happens if you switch it off?

Comment: I checked by disabling multi views but I got the same error msg, 'More than 10 redirects instead of no file found'. When I enabled that error msg is same i.e 'More than 10 redirects instead of no file found'. Is there any other options. Its the problem with alias,without alias it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have this line in your application.ini file?

```
resources.frontController.baseUrl = "/xyz"
```